# error CS1002: ; expected & (31,13): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'else'

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with layout, I know I am close. /// I have two errors that are (`31,18): error CS1002: ; expected & (31,13): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'else'` /// I have tried to do what was said and it made more errors, so I am totally don't know how to make this work now.

At the moment I have this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CE0721a
{
    class Tut4_7
    {
        public void run()
          {
            double under16_Free = 2.5;
            double oap = 3.0;
            double other = 5.0;
            int groupSize = 0;
            double totalCost = 0;
            int age = 0;

        while (age!=-1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an Age or -1 to quit");
            age=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(age<16)&(age>-1);
            {
                groupSize++;
                totalCost = totalCost + under16_Free;
            }
            else if(age>16)
            {
                groupSize++;
                totalCost = totalCost + oap;
            }
            else if(age>16)&(age<=65);
            {
                groupSize++;
                totalCost = totalCost + other;
            }
        }
        if (groupSize>6)
        {
            totalCost = totalCost - (totalCost/5);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total Cost = "(totalCost));
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do this

**Write a program, for the local swimming pool that displays the admission cost for a group of people based on their age. The program should continue to prompt the user to enter an age until –1 is entered, and then display the total number of people in the group and the total cost for that group. Admission fees are as follows: 
 - under 16’s  £2.50 over 65 -£3  and all other swimmers - £5

A 20% discount should be applied to groups of more than 6 people.**

This is connected to another cs called Program.cs, laid out like this and works, because I have tested with other cs files, this displays the program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CE0721a
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tut4_7 myProgram = new Tut4_7();
            myProgram.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again, if anyone can help

Comment: else if(age>16)&(age<=65); remove the semicolon from that line for a starter.

Comment: have you examined line 31? The error messages should tell you that you have a syntax error. You might check the C# language spec and see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CE0721a
{
    class Tut4_7
    {
        public void run() 
          { 
            double under16_Free = 2.5; 
            double oap = 3.0; 
            double other = 5.0; 
            int groupSize = 0; 
            double totalCost = 0; 
            int age = 0; 

        while (age!=-1) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an Age or -1 to quit"); 
            age=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

            if((age<16)&&(age>-1))
            { 
                groupSize++; 
                totalCost = totalCost + under16_Free; 
            } 
            else if(age>16) 
            { 
                groupSize++; 
                totalCost = totalCost + oap; 
            } 
            else if((age>16)&&(age<=65))
            { 
                groupSize++; 
                totalCost = totalCost + other; 
            } 
        } 
        if (groupSize>6) 
        { 
            totalCost = totalCost - (totalCost/5); 
        } 
        Console.WriteLine("Total Cost = " + totalCost); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved, it for me thank you ^_^ I did have to change else if(age>16) to else if (age > 65) & add Console.WriteLine("Number of people = " + groupSize); under Console.WriteLine("Total Cost = " + totalCost); which I thought about, after I asked for help. Again thank you

Answer (score 6):

A few syntax issues:

- the opening line of an if statement should not end in a semi colon
- you need another set of parentheses around your compound comparison
- you almost always want to use `&&` instead of `&` as the former will short circuit

So

```
if(age<16)&(age>-1);
```

Should become

```
if ((age<16) && (age>-1))
```

Or, as @Servy mentioned in the comments

```
if (age<16 && age>-1)
```

Comment: the comparison operators have a higher precedence than the `&&` operator.  You don't need the parenthesis around those operations.

Answer (score 2):

You have semi-colons at the end of a few of your if/else statements, and you're using the wrong logical operator:

```
if(age<16)&(age>-1);
```

should be

```
if(age < 16 && age >= 1)
{
    //Code here
}
```

and

```
else if(age>16)&(age<=65);
```

should be

```
else if(age > 16 && age <= 65)
{
    //Code here
}
```

You want to use the `&&` operator instead of the `&` operator, and @Servy gives a nice explanation of why in the comments.

Comment: Actually, the `&` operator can take either bytes/numeric values and do bit shifting or it can take boolean values.  When it is given boolean values it will perform a regular boolean AND that doesn't short circuit, while the && operator does short circuit.  It's useful if the second operand causes side effects that you always and to happen (which you shouldn't do, because that's just mean code).  So, yes, he should change it to `&&`, but just for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(age<16)&(age>-1);
```

Three problems:

- First, you shouldn't add a ; after the if statement, that would cause
  nothing (empty statement) to get executed.
- The second problem are the brackets. You are closing the breakets in
  your if condition. You can't close them and reopen them, but you
  could use brackets to seperate parts in the outer brackets.
- The last problem is the AND operator. You use the binary AND & and
  not the logical AND &&.

The line should look like:

```
if(age<16 && age>-1)
```

The same thing applies to the other line.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this:

```
 if(age<16)&(age>-1);
```

Should be `&&`. You want a logical and not a bitwise and.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
if ( (age<16) & (age>-1))
```

Syntax

```
if(condition)
{
  //Treatment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement are badly formed, you are using the binary & not the logical && and both conditions only need to be in a single () , and most importantly you don't need to semi colon after a if statment, that signifys the end

```
namespace CE0721a
{
    class Tut4_7
    {
        public void run()
          {
            double under16_Free = 2.5;
            double oap = 3.0;
            double other = 5.0;
            int groupSize = 0;
            double totalCost = 0;
            int age = 0;

        while (age!=-1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an Age or -1 to quit");
            age=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(age<16 && age>-1)
            {
                groupSize++;
                totalCost = totalCost + under16_Free;
            }
            else if(age>16)
            {
                groupSize++;
                totalCost = totalCost + oap;
            }
            else if(age>16 && age<=65)
            {
                groupSize++;
                totalCost = totalCost + other;
            }
        }
        if (groupSize>6)
        {
            totalCost = totalCost - (totalCost/5);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total Cost = "(totalCost));
        }
    }
}
```